# Interpreting the Dask UI

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I was looking at the Dask UI and trying to figure out what each field means. However, I was not able to make sense of the *write_bytes* and *read_bytes* that can be shown in the image below. Also, the number of write_bytes is more than read_bytes in some cases. I was not able to find any documentation regarding this. What exactly do *write_bytes* and *read_bytes* mean?

I am running a simple Logistic Regression task on the MNIST data using Joblib dask backend.
[Dask UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upRx2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those fields are about network traffic going in and out of that worker process.

Answer (score 1):

These are common computing terms, referring to measurement of bytes written out over a network interface, and measurement of bytes read in from a network interface.

It's a bandwidth utilisation meaurement.

Some tools (like Windows' Resource Monitor) call this "Sent" and "Received" instead.